# How to handle hidden elements in Cypress with if statement?

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I have an element job-ad which is dynamic i want it to be handle when it’s displayed and not displayed

For example if .job-ad is displayed log me a text it’s Visible, but else log it’s hidden. I tried it with below approach but it keeps me throwing an error that the #JobAdCard is hidden (that’s where i want to show the ‘it’s hidden)

Here's my approach;

```
cy.get('.job-ad', {failOnStatusCode: false})
 .then(($jobAd) => {
    if ($jobAd.length > 0 && $jobAd.is(':visible')) {
       cy.log('JOB CARD IS VISIBLE');
    } else {
       cy.log('JOB CARD IS HIDDEN');
  }
});
```

and the error that i get;
`Timed out retrying after 1000ms: Expected to find element: .job-ad, but never found it.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
  if (body.find('.job-ad').length > 0) {
      cy.log('JOB CARD IS VISIBLE')
  }
  else {
      cy.log('JOB CARD IS HIDDEN');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for joining SO! Your answer is correct, but you could improve your answer by providing context on how your answer solves the problem posed by OP. It is more effective to teach someone _how_ to solve the issue on their own than to only post the answer with no additional context.

Comment: This answer cannot be correct, it does not test for visibility.